# What’s the name of a fallacy where a proposed solution is only discussed in terms of benefits?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

As an example, mandating that every single car driver wears a motorcycle helmet would probably reduce the number of deaths and head injuries from car accidents. But of course it would be highly impractical as all drivers would be sweating profusely inside the helmet due to the lack of wind that’s present when riding a motorbike.

What’s the name of a fallacy where the person talks about a policy (“let’s all wear helmets!”) but completely ignores the downsides?

Comment: I don't know if it's a formal fallacy, but it would be a *one-sided argument.*

Comment: Sounds like wishful thinking.

Comment: Seems like a form of cherry-picking

Comment: or campaign pledge...

Comment: I'm not sure there's enough detail here to answer the question.  Fallacies are about arguments; policies are not arguments (just statements of standards); and the example "mandating that every single car driver wears a motorcycle helmet would probably reduce the number of deaths and head injuries from car accidents" is just a prediction, not an argument.

Comment: It's the pro-side…

Answer (score 1):

[Peter Suber has written an article](http://legacy.earlham.edu/%7Epeters/courses/inflogic/onesided.htm) ([archive link](https://web.archive.org/web/20210211011449/http://legacy.earlham.edu/%7Epeters/courses/inflogic/onesided.htm)) describing this kind of argument; he calls it the "one-sidedness fallacy."

> The fallacy consists of giving reasons for your thesis without considering reasons against it, or giving reasons against an opposing view without considering reasons for it.
> [....]
>
> The one-sidedness fallacy does not make an argument invalid. It may not even make the argument unsound. The fallacy consists in persuading readers, and perhaps ourselves, that we have said enough to tilt the scale of evidence and therefore enough to justify a judgment. If we have been one-sided, though, then we haven't yet said enough to justify a judgment. The arguments on the other side may be stronger than our own. We won't know until we examine them.

Comment: As the author implies, this doesn't fit the definition of a true *fallacy*, "**a mistaken belief**, especially one based on unsound argument." (Oxford).

Comment: "One-sided analysis" word work just as well.  The concept of a fallacy as a kind of 'belief' is contentious at best.  The intro here is informative https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/fallacies/